# How can I make 1 cycle self rising signal in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'm not familiar with verilog, but I'd like to make as below PKTEND signal.
as you can see that, that signal is go to back to rising from falling when FLAGA has fallen.

[image]

I'd like to make such that PKTEND signal.
would you please let me know how to make that signal in verilog?

```
module test ();

input flagA;
input flagB;
output pktend;
input clk;
input reset_n;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
if(!flagA) begin
pktend <= 1;
pktend <= 0;
pktend <= 1;
end

end



endmodule
```

Comment: You can only change value once per `posedge clk` try something closer to `pktend <= ~pktend;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog (and HDLs more generally) are not C - they (by and large) don't operate in a sequential manner. The lines

```
if(!flagA) begin
  pktend <= 1;
  pktend <= 0;
  pktend <= 1;
end
```

are equivalent to

```
if(!flagA) begin
  pktend <= 1;
end
```

since the three assignments to `pktend` all occur in the same instance in time.

What you're looking for is something more akin to the following:

```
always@(posedge clk)
  flagA_prev <= flagA;

always @(negedge clk)
  if (!flagA && flagA_prev) //The flag was asserted up until now
    pktend <= 0;
  else
    pktend <= 1;
```

You might need an additional cycle of delay to match the diagram correctly - I'll leave that for you to figure out. I've set `pktend` to change on the negative edge, so that it's stable on the positive edge if its being captured by an external device - you might need to change this, depending on your application requirements.